# Widgets not rendering in Voila

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets, voila

I have code which executes widgets fine in jupyter labs but does not render the widgets in voila. See the image for the example from the voila github.
[image]

Python version 3.10.9

voila 0.3.6

jupyterlab 3.5.3

ipywidgets 7.6.5

Comment: You aren't handling the display of the widget output. You need to specifically link the widget objects you make to how to display them in the output handler of JupyterLab, and **importantly for your issue, Voila**. Right now your code just invokes widgets objects. Voila doesn't automatically display them. I'm actually surprised JupyterLab is displaying them as well. It tends to be more strict than the older notebook interface, and so it is better for developing for Voila.  The easiest way is to look at other **current** Voila examples and build on those. I'll try to point at some later.

Comment: <continued> See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/problem-displaying-output-from-voila-page/5635/2?u=fomightez) and [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/widget-button-to-open-url/11634/2?u=fomightez) for discussions relating to the issue you are facing. There's more advances examples at [the Voila Gallery](https://voila-gallery.org/) to mine for code examples.